# Why the JavaScript only executes the last line of the function?

Tags: javascript, function

```
function operation(value_01, value_02) {

    const sum = value_01 + value_02;

    const sub = value_01 - value_02;

    const multi = value_01 * value_02;

    const div = value_01 / value_02;

    return (`The Sum is ${sum}`, `The Subtraction is ${sub}`, `The Multiplication is ${multi}`, `The 
    Division is ${div}`);
}

console.log(operation(10, 5));
```

Comment: It's executing the whole function. `return (x, y, x)` just returns the value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this.

```
return (`The Sum is ${sum}, The Subtraction is ${sub}, The Multiplication is ${multi}, The Division is ${div}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn’t support functions that return multiple values. However, you can wrap multiple values into an array or an object and return the array or the object.
Just make that last return line to return a single object / value and you are good to go.